# Commercial vs Transactional Send Classification in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, email-studio, sfmc-business-unit

We are doing confirmation of consent change emails from SFMC to customers that are added to our Sales Cloud instance. For this purpose, we are leveraging Sales Cloud data in Journey Builder via the MCC connector. Now, we cannot decide whether to use Commercial or Transactional Send Classification for this. Are there any practical differences between the two classifications (e.g. different report/tracking folders, additional items added to the footer such us default SF unsubscribe button, etc.)? We are using a custom consent preference page hosted on our 3-rd party website; so nothing is done in SFMC in regards to unsubscribes or consent changes (except for RMMs). Thanks

Comment: You will most likely never find unsubscribe possibilities inside transactional mails. because they are only used for important non commercial communications like invoices etc.

Answer (score 1):

Transactional Send Classifications:

- Ignore Status "unsubscribed" on the All Subscribers List and send anyway. (They do respect status "held".)
- do not feature a list-unsubscribe header in the Email headers.

Commercial Classifications do the opposite. (and of course also respect "held" status)

In short: You cannot unsubscribe from Transactional Messages.

So much for the actual technical basis.

What is "right" in your case can be a legal question, so you will not get a definitive answer.

The idea behind transactional classifications is that they should ONLY be used if the emails in question HAVE to be sent for a (typically) customer-triggered transaction to complete, even if the user wants no marketing communication.

common examples, again, from "practice", not legal advice:

- "forgot my password" email for some customer account. The customer needs and triggers this, regardless of his subscriptions for a newsletter.
- "Double Opt In Confirmation Request" emails - if the user demonstrably WANTS to re-subscribe, this message HAS to be sent or that transaction cannot be completed.

Answer (score 1):

Transactional Email:- 1) In transitional email contains only your transactional receipt/purchase details/bill receipts 2) we can send transactional email to unsubscribe people also. 3) In transactional email no need to put unsubscribe link.

Commercial Email:- 1) In commercial email includes something advertisement/promotional contains. 2) We can not send commercial email to Unsubscribe people list 3) In commercial email its necessary to include unsubscribe link & sender physical mailing address.