# Transactional email behavior using the Send Flow

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email, ui, transactional-messaging-api

I am new to transactional emails in Marketing Cloud and am being presented with a business case where marketers want to send legal updates to customers based on certain legal business requirements i.e. your business license is about to expire, your business is out of state compliance etc. These marketers want to control the send themselves.

I have read up on the transactional API, triggered send definitions and Journey builder methods, but using the good ole marketing cloud UI and send flow, is it possible to send transactional style emails to a predefined list using the transactional send classification? Follow up would be if selected in the send classification, would subscriber marketing status be ignored (ignoring "held")

Yes, I understand the legal CAN-SPAM ramifications and such, just wondering if that is an option outside of the above mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the message would still deliver to Held subscribers if Transactional Send Classification was chosen.

You can set messages up to through Triggered Sends or Journeys.

The transactional send should be triggered by a user action though, clicking Forgot Password on your site for example. Arguably sending an email to a customer telling them a license is expiring could be seen as a marketing email and not a transactional receipt following an interaction.

Here is a good answer on this: [Commercial vs Transactional Send Classification in SFMC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/340505/commercial-vs-transactional-send-classification-in-sfmc)